# Finding range index of a sorted array on a specific element

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I am working with array where the set is sorted. The task is to find the range of a value.

Lets assume we have this sorted array:

```
int[] array = {1,1,1,3,3,9,10}
```

**Example**
We have to find the range- min and max for the element 1. We quickly spot that the first index of the element 1 is 0, and the range max is 2.

We now know that the range between 0 and 2 all have value 1. If the searched element is 3 we see that range is 3-4, and for the element 9 the range is 6-6.

I have used linear search to do this, but would hear, if there is a more faster way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use two versions of binary search to find the leftmost and rightmost positions:

```
int[] array = { 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 9, 10 }
int value = ...

int leftmost(int min, int max)
{
    if (min == max) return min
    int mid = (min + max) / 2

    if (array[mid] < value) return leftmost(mid + 1, max)
    else return leftmost(min, mid)
}

int rightmost(int min, int max)
{
    if (min == max) return min
    int mid = (min + max + 1) / 2

    if (array[mid] > value) return rightmost(min, mid - 1)
    else return rightmost(mid, max)
}
```

Just make the calls with `min=0` and `max=array.length-1`. Time complexity is `O(logn)`.

You will get outputs like this (`0-based` indexes):

```
value=1  -> left=0, right=2
value=3  -> left=3, right=4
value=9  -> left=5, right=5
value=10 -> left=6, right=6
```

Comment: Time complexity will be logn and not nlog(n)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using exactly this formulation because if the search value is not in the array, you still return some valid index. Better to use a traditional `if (min > max) return -1` early exit. Then you'd have to come up with a new check to determine success...

Answer (score 0):

Binary search will be much faster. You can get some insight on this [here](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/binary-search/a/implementing-binary-search-of-an-array)

Comment: The problem with binary search is that it only return one index.

E.g. if we search for element 1, it will return 1 as index. But I am searching for a range.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a larger array go with binary and then linear.

Depending on the size of the array the faster way might be linear.
If you are doing this search repeatedly with arrays of 7 numbers like you have you aren't going to see much performance difference. It would probably be slower in fact.

However, expand that array though so that you have more and you would be better off with doing a binary search initially and then doing the linear search.

Do it once and grab the bottom part of the range and then do linear to find the end point of the range.

You could do another binary for the end point but over time that should average out to a wash with a plain linear function.

Answer (score 0):

While the answer from @Arturo Menchaca is correct, I think the recursive solution can be bit challenging to understand. So, for those who prefer an ***iterative*** approach...

```
public int[] FindRange(int[] arr, int value)
{
    int[] upperLowerBounds = new int[2];
    int startIndex = 0;
    int endIndex = arr.Length - 1;
    while (startIndex < endIndex)
    {
        int midIndex = (startIndex + endIndex) / 2;
        if (value <= arr[midIndex])
        {
            endIndex = midIndex;
        }
        else
        {
            startIndex = midIndex + 1;
        }
    }

    // saving startIndex in the result array that will be returned...
    upperLowerBounds[0] = startIndex;
    endIndex = arr.Length - 1;
    while (startIndex < endIndex)
    {
        int midIndex = (startIndex + endIndex) / 2 + 1;
        if (value < arr[midIndex])
        {
            endIndex = midIndex  -1;
        }
        else
        {
            startIndex = midIndex;
        }
    }

    upperLowerBounds[1] = endIndex;
    return upperLowerBounds;
}
```

and the unit tests..

```
[TestCase(new int[] { -4, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -1, 1, 6, 8, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 25 }, -3, 1, 9)] // search element = -3
[TestCase(new int[] { -4, -3, -1, 1, 6, 8, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 25 }, 6, 4, 4)] // search element = 6
[TestCase(new int[] { -4, -3, -1, 1, 6, 8, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 25 }, 10, 6, 11)] // search element = 10
[TestCase(new int[] { -4, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 6, 8, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 25 }, -1, 10, 17)] // search element = -1
[TestCase(new int[] { 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 9, 10 }, 3, 3, 4)] // search element  = 3
[TestCase(new int[] { 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 9, 10 }, 1, 0, 2)] // search element = 1
public void FindRangeTest(int[] arr, int value, int expectedStartIndex, int expectedEndIndex)
{
    int[] range = runner.FindRange(arr, value);

    // Assert.
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedStartIndex, range[0]);
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedEndIndex, range[1]);
}
```

I have used C# and nunit [3.10](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnit/3.10.1)